# Title search - Fiction time travel to 1960s - Not Asimov

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a novel from roughly mid 80s to early 90s. The main character meets a man in San Francisco who turns out to be a time traveling alien. The cover was very psychedelic. He takes her to the future and they fall in love. Any ideas? I want to say his name was Michael?

Comment: Can you give ANY more details?

Comment: Doesn't sound too broad to me.  Assuming the OP's description is accurate (memories can be confused as we know) someone who has read that novel in that edition would surely be able to identify it from "time travel", "San Francisco", "psychedelic" cover, and "male alien taking female into the future".  How many novels are going to match that?

Comment: Voted to reopen, see comment above. Terse, yes, but not enough to warrant a "too broad" closure, IMO. If you're going to vote "Leave Closed", please provide, say, 2-3 examples of a book 1/ written in 80s-90s 2/ with MC named Michael 3/ psychedelic cover 4/ in San Francisco 5/with time-travel, etc, etc.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)